# How to write inline assembly with floating points

Tags: gcc, assembly, floating-point, x86, inline-assembly

I am writing a simple program where I am assigning value of one float to another.

```
float a = 1;
float b = 2;
b=a;
```

I want to convert the "b=a" line to inline assembly. I have written the following:

```
asm volatile("movss %1, %%xmm0 \n"
             "movss %%xmm0, %0"
             :"=f"(b)
             :"f"(a)
             :"xmm0");
```

It gives the following error:

```
a.c:8:17: error: output constraint 0 must specify a single register
                 asm volatile("movss %1, %%xmm0 \n"
```

Can anybody help me out with what this error means and how to debug it?

P.S - The CPU Architecture info if anyone needs it.

```
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                8
```

Thank you

Comment: The `f` constraint is for the FPU registers. See the [manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Machine-Constraints.html). Anyway, it's pointless to convert that as it is basically a no-op just force the same register for the operands using for example `asm volatile("" :"=x" (b) :"0"(a));`.

Comment: You should also consider using gcc's [builtins](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Built-in-Functions.html) for utilizing the xmm registers (for example __builtin_ia32_movss) and [avoid using inline asm](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DontUseInlineAsm).